# How can I use local variable from one function and use them in another function, if this is even possible?

Tags: javascript

**My Problem**

I have a function called `mathsFormula()` which is supposed to calculate the two input fields located in the second function called `renderRow()` and display that answer in the `<div>` labelled result.

However, I don't know how to attach the local variables from renderRow() function so they work inside the mathsFormula().

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

**This is the mathsFormula() function**

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", mathsFormula());

function mathsFormula() {

const calculate = (input1.value * input2.value) - input2.value; 
result.textContent = calculate

}
```

**This is the renderRow() function**

```
function renderRow() {
  
  const row = document.createElement('div');

  const label = document.createElement("label");
  
  const input1 = document.createElement("input");
  input1.type = "number";
    
  const input2 = document.createElement("input");
  input2.type = "number";
  
  const result = document.createElement("div");

  row.append(label, input1, input2, result);
```

Comment: Define the variables outside of the function as global variables and change their values with the functions... Basically ommit "const" before the variable names. For example your result_div should be available globally as you didn't define it as a new const.
Another solution would be to *return* the variables in your functions and then simply call your functions within other functions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose these variables by returning them from the function. You can return them in an object, e.g. `return { bet_label, input_field, input_div };`, so when the function is called it will return an object containing references to these elements.

```js
function addRow(rowNumber) {

  const bet_label = document.createElement("label");
  a.appendChild(bet_label);
  bet_label.classList.add('betLabel');
  bet_label.textContent = "Bet " + rowNumber;

  const input_field = document.createElement("input");
  a.appendChild(input_field);
  input_field.classList.add('oddsEntry');
  input_field.type = "number";

  const input_div = document.createElement("input");
  a.appendChild(input_div);
  input_div.classList.add('stakeEntry');
  input_div.type = "number";

  const result_div = document.createElement("div");
  a.appendChild(result_div)
  result_div.classList.add('resultDiv');
  result_div.textContent = "";

  const btn_Del = document.createElement("button");
  btn_Del.classList.add('deleteBtn');
  btn_Del.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
  a.appendChild(btn_Del);

  return {
    bet_label,
    input_field,
    input_div,
    result_div,
    btn_Del
  };
}
```